# merging rows from sql query result

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, gridview

What would it be the simplest way to merge a result like this from a sql query to be displayed in an asp.net gridview?

```
NULL   Tarde Fer  W. Lunes
Mañana NULL  Fer  W. Lunes
```

I need the result to look like this

```
Mañana Tarde Fer  W. Lunes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Table

```
Col1      Col2     Col3    Col4
-------   ------   ------  --------
NULL      Tarde    Fer     W. Lunes
Mañana    NULL     Fer     W. Lunes
```

Then

```
SELECT MAX(Col1) AS Col1, MAX(Col2) AS Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Col3, Col4
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it upstream from the UI (on the server returning the results, in other words,) and group on an ID field returning the max() field values when you want to exclude nulls.